# cxgrid ban change band for columns

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

How I can ban change band for columns?

I need for moving for group-by function, but I dont need change band for columns.
So I cant change Moving property in column options.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to affect the Options/HoldOwnsColumsOnly of your band ?

It will work in your case.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you sure this is an answer to the question? it looks like a comment to it. Also, I'm editing your question to remove the signature, as per the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Im newbee in using VCL controls.